# ViewGroup will be null when came back from another fragment that we call from a current fragment in navigation component android

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, nullpointerexception, android-architecture-navigation

I used Navigation Component in my app. in one of my fragments (let's call it FragmentA) I have many fields. and in this fragment, I define a Radio Group for Visible/Gone in some fields. everything works perfectly when I came from HomeFragment into FragmentA,  but when I go from FragmentA to another destination that is fragment too (and let's call it, for example, FragmentB) and handle all this with Navigation Component and then try back into again FragmentA, I got Null Pointer for view group as `unknown Source` with this message: `Parameter specified as non-null is null`. and this is my code for handle Visible/Gone fields.

```
  private fun showChildren(v: View, isShow: Boolean) {

    val viewGroup = v as ViewGroup
    for (i in 0 until viewGroup.childCount) {
        val v1 = viewGroup.getChildAt(i)
        (v1 as? ViewGroup)?.let { showChildren(it, isShow) }

        if (v1.tag == "check_for_visibility" && isShow) {
            v1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else if (v1.tag == "check_for_visibility" && !isShow) {
            v1.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

may please guide me on how I can handle this null pointer exception with ViewGroup when came back from FragmentB to FragmentA?

edit:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController



class AddPickupContinuousParentFragment :
    BaseFragment<FragmentAddPickupContinuousParentBinding, AddPickupContinuousParentViewModel>(
        R.layout.fragment_add_pickup_continuous_parent,
        AddPickupContinuousParentViewModel()
    ) {

    private var kindOfRentList: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
    private var selectedRent = ""

    override fun initVariables() {
        binding.addPickupContinuousParentViewModel = vModel
    }

    override fun initObserves() {

    }

    override fun initViews() {

        val receivedWaybill =
            arguments?.let { AddPickupContinuousParentFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).waybill }
        val receivedClosedArray =
            arguments?.let { AddPickupContinuousParentFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).closedArray }

        if (receivedWaybill != null && receivedWaybill != "0") {
            if (receivedWaybill.isNotEmpty()) {

                binding.layoutCargo.etNewPickupWaybill.isEnabled = false
                binding.layoutCargo.etNewPickupWaybill.setText(receivedWaybill)
            }
        }

        if (receivedClosedArray != null) {
            if (receivedClosedArray.isNotEmpty()) {
                binding.layoutCargo.etNewPickupClosedCount.isEnabled = false
                binding.layoutCargo.etNewPickupClosedCount.setText(receivedClosedArray.size.toString())
            }
        }


        val countries: Array<out String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.countries_array)
        ArrayAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            countries
        ).also {
            binding.layoutSender.autoAddSenderStateCity.setAdapter(it)
            binding.layoutReceiver.autoAddReceiverStateCity.setAdapter(it)


        // spinner init
        kindOfRentList.add("test1")
        kindOfRentList.add("test2")
        val kindOfRentAdapter =
            ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, kindOfRentList)
        kindOfRentAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        binding.layoutCargo.spinnerNewPickupKindRent.adapter =
            kindOfRentAdapter
        selectedRent = kindOfRentList[0]

        binding.layoutCargo.spinnerNewPickupKindRent.onItemSelectedListener =
            object : OnItemSelectedListener {
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>,
                    view: View,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    selectedRent =
                        binding.layoutCargo.spinnerNewPickupKindRent.selectedItem.toString()
                }

                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
            }

        // visible or gone fields
        vModel.editTextVisibility.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            Observer {
                if (it == true) {

                    binding.radioNewPickupNo.setTextColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            requireContext(),
                            R.color.red
                        )
                    )
                    binding.radioNewPickupYes.setTextColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            requireContext(),
                            R.color.lightGray
                        )
                    )

                    activity?.window?.decorView?.let { it1 ->
                        showChildren(it1, true)
                    }
                } else {

                    binding.radioNewPickupNo.setTextColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            requireContext(),
                            R.color.lightGray
                        )
                    )
                    binding.radioNewPickupYes.setTextColor(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            requireContext(),
                            R.color.green
                        )
                    )

                    activity?.window?.decorView?.let { it1 -> showChildren(it1, false) }
                }
            })


        val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "fa");

        binding.layoutSender.imgAddSenderName.setOnClickListener {

            startActivityForResult(intent, 700)
        }

        binding.layoutSender.imgAddSenderAddress.setOnClickListener {

            startActivityForResult(intent, 701)
        }

        binding.layoutSender.imgAddSenderCompany.setOnClickListener {

            startActivityForResult(intent, 702)
        }

        binding.layoutReceiver.imgAddReceiverName.setOnClickListener {

            startActivityForResult(intent, 703)
        }

        binding.layoutReceiver.imgAddReceiverAddress.setOnClickListener {

            startActivityForResult(intent, 704)
        }

        binding.layoutReceiver.imgAddReceiverCompany.setOnClickListener {

            startActivityForResult(intent, 705)
        }

        binding.btnAddPickupRegister.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addPickupContinuousParentFragment_to_finalizeCargoFragment)
        }

    }


    override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ) {

        when (requestCode) {

            700 -> {
                try {
                    if (data != null) {
                        val result: String? = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS
                        )[0]

                        binding.layoutSender.etAddSenderName.setText(result)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            701 -> {
                try {
                    if (data != null) {
                        val result: String? = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS
                        )[0]

                        binding.layoutSender.etAddSenderAddress.setText(result)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            702 -> {
                try {
                    if (data != null) {
                        val result: String? = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS
                        )[0]

                        binding.layoutSender.etAddSenderCompany.setText(result)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            703 -> {
                try {
                    if (data != null) {
                        val result: String? = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS
                        )[0]

                        binding.layoutReceiver.etAddReceiverName.setText(result)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            704 -> {
                try {
                    if (data != null) {
                        val result: String? = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS
                        )[0]

                        binding.layoutReceiver.etAddReceiverAddress.setText(result)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }

            705 -> {
                try {
                    if (data != null) {
                        val result: String? = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS
                        )[0]

                        binding.layoutReceiver.etAddReceiverCompany.setText(result)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private fun showChildren(v: View, isShow: Boolean) {

        try {
            val viewGroup = v as ViewGroup
            for (i in 0 until viewGroup.childCount) {
                val v1 = viewGroup.getChildAt(i)
                (v1 as? ViewGroup)?.let { showChildren(it, isShow) }

                if (v1.tag == "check_for_visibility" && isShow) {
                    v1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else if (v1.tag == "check_for_visibility" && !isShow) {
                    v1.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting popUpTo attribute in the NavigationGraph's action. Navigation Controller simply recreates the fragment and does not maintain the state. That is why everything is getting reset.

Also please add your Fragment classes. Thanks.

Comment: I try to add pop to in navigation graph for FragmentA and FragmentB but still get Null pointer exception for ViewGroup. and edit the post to add FragmentA code. 
@karandhillon